# What's best image cache busting in CSS files with Webpack 2?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-2, postcss

I have been using [postcss-cachebuster](https://github.com/glebmachine/postcss-cachebuster) with GruntJS and it works well. Now I want to migrate to **Webpack 2**, with [postcss-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader). Tried following packages but none of them work, image URLs in url() are unchanged in final CSS output (via `file-loader`).

- postcss-cachebuster
- [postcss-assets](https://github.com/borodean/postcss-assets)
- [postcss-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/klimashkin/postcss-assets-webpack-plugin)